# $(this) is undefined and doesn't return selector using the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem using the function `main()` on 2 different events. The first event is this:

```
$buttonStart.on('click', main);
```

In the second event I need to do other things too so it's like this:

```
$buttonDelay.on('click', function () {
    otherFunction();
    main();
});
```

The `main()` function uses a jQuery function at the end:

```
$(this).ripple(100);
```

So, the problem is that in the first case it works perfectly, meanwhile in the second case it says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

I have no idea on what to do to fix this and why it behaves this differently.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `main.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: *"why it behaves this differently"* Because in the second example, `main` is called differently than in the first example. You need to [learn about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Function.prototype.call()` to set `this` to `$buttonDelay` at `otherFunction`, `main`, you can also pass the event object to the functions as second parameter to `.call()`

```
$buttonDelay.on("click", function (event) {
    otherFunction.call(this, event);
    main.call(this, event);
});
```